# How to identify type of syscall in arm processor?

Tags: c, arm, system-calls, cpu-registers

```
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/user.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>   /* For SYS_write etc */
int main()
{   pid_t child;
    long orig_eax, eax;
    long params[3];
    int status;
    int insyscall = 0;
    child = fork();
    if(child == 0) {
        ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, NULL, NULL);
        execl("/bin/ls", "ls", NULL);
    }
    else {
       while(1) {
          wait(&status);
          if(WIFEXITED(status))
              break;
          orig_eax = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER,
                     child, 4 * ORIG_EAX, NULL);
          if(orig_eax == SYS_write) {
                 ......
            }
            ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL,
                   child, NULL, NULL);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code doesn't work in arm because in arm there is no `ORIG_EAX` register.

How can you tell which kind of `syscall` was caught in ARM architectures? Something like `ioctl` or `recv` ?

Comment: @OznOg I don't understand your comment

Comment: @OznOg Took me a while to as well :)

Comment: @Uiomkokf Don't use `linux/user.h`; it's not available on some platforms. Instead, use `sys/reg.h` or `asm/ptrace-abi.h`.

Comment: syscalls are defined by the operating system not arm.

Comment: syscall# is passed in r7 on ARM.  See: [Architecture calling conventions](https://gist.github.com/yamnikov-oleg/454f48c3c45b735631f2) and [man syscall](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html).  eax is the syscall# and return value on x86.  Orig_r0 is the first parameter and r0 is the return on the ARM.  R7 will the the syscall# with an strace register dump.